# I want 3 toolbars floating on each side and bottom of the screen and SVG should take rest of the space. How to model this?

Tags: javascript, css, html, svg

[image]

I want a full screen page without scrolling. The page should take out the entire screen with 3 toolbars ( 2 on both sides of the screen and a bottom toolbar ). how can i set svg dimensions?. Help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your CSS you could try using "calc()".

As an example:

```
.my-svg-container {
    height: calc(100vh - 50px - 40px);
    width: calc(100vw - 20px - 10px);
}
```

Where: Top bar = 50px, Bottom bar = 40px, Left bar = 20px, and Right bar = 10px

Should note that this method will only work if you know the dimensions of each bar, otherwise you could just use "height: (a number)vh; width: (a number)vw;" where (a number) is a number between 0 - 100 and represents a percentage of the screen size (i.e. where 100vh is 100% screen height, 40vw is 40% screen width)

Comment: I didn't use calc, vh or vw because i want to support the older browser. So I made the calculations in Javascript. Thanks alot for the quick answer and giving me the idea to solve it. :)